# Removing a timer created with "systemd-run --on-calendar"

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I've created a systemd job using `systemd-run --on-calendar ....` Now I've replaced it with proper `.timer` and `.service` files, but I'm not able to remove the old one. I can stop it and disable it, but when I call `systemctl list-timers` it still appears with its arbitrary name `run-r0d0dc22...`. I also looked for its `.timer` file, but I couldn't find them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The transient files end up in `/run/user/` and do not seem to ever be removed until the user logs out (for `systemd-run --user`) or until a reboot, when `/run` is recreated.

For example, if you create a command to run once only at a given time:

```
systemd-run --user --on-calendar '2017-08-12 14:46' /bin/bash -c 'echo done >/tmp/done'
```

You will get files owned by you in `/run`:

```
/run/user/1000/systemd/user/run-28810.service
/run/user/1000/systemd/user/run-28810.service.d/50-Description.conf
/run/user/1000/systemd/user/run-28810.service.d/50-ExecStart.conf
/run/user/1000/systemd/user/run-28810.timer
/run/user/1000/systemd/user/run-28810.timer.d/50-Description.conf
/run/user/1000/systemd/user/run-28810.timer.d/50-OnCalendar.conf
```

For non `--user` the files are in `/run/systemd/system/`

You can remove the files, do a `systemctl [--user] daemon-reload` and 
then `list-timers` will show only the Unit name, with their last history if they have already run. This information is probably held within systemd's internal status or journal files.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer (remove the files and do a `daemon-reload`) did not work for me - instead I was able to remove the timer using `systemd --user stop unitfile`; this might differ in that I was already using a unit file, however.

---

Because my question, 'Systemd as `at` replacement' has been marked as an "exact duplicate", I shall delete it and post the content below.

I'd like to use systemd like `at`. I've created a unit file in `~/.config/systemd/user/say@.service` which runs a shell script (passing "%I"), but am having trouble scheduling it. If I use `systemd-run --user --unit say@'test message' --on-calendar='13:54'` it keeps the timer active to run tomorrow as well, instead of deleting it once it has run.

How should I instruct systemd to run a unit file exactly once at a specific time today? I would like a solution which automatically cleans up the transient timer as well, so I don't have to `systemd --user stop say@'test message'` afterwards.

---

Answer: I had to specify the full date. So - `... --on-calendar='2018-04-16 13:54:00'`. This appears to clean up after itself properly as well.

Comment: I had to solve this same problem a week ago and I couldn't quickly find or remember how to use `systemd` as an `at` replacement... so I just installed `at`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do

```
systemctl --user stop Remove_Me.{service,timer}
```

with systemd version 245 to remove the transient timer unit.

The `{service,timer}` part is a Bash feature: [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)

---

[Iiridayn's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385490/removing-a-timer-created-with-systemd-run-on-calendar#438185) of running `systemctl --user stop Remove_Me` did not work for me, I got this:

> Warning: Stopping Remove_Me.service, but it can still be activated by:
>   Remove_Me.timer

and the unit still showed up with `systemctl --user list-timers *Remove*`.

Reading [meuh's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385490/removing-a-timer-created-with-systemd-run-on-calendar#385681), I found the .timer and .service file in `/run/user/1000/systemd/transient/`. After deleting the files and doing `systemctl --user daemon-reload` there was still the `Remove_Me.timer` (but no `Remove_Me.service`) in the output of `systemctl --user list-timers`.

I got rid of that lingering timer by readding the unit with

```
systemd-run --user --on-calendar=2025-01-01 -u "Remove_Me" touch ~/test_file
```

and then removing it with

```
systemctl --user stop Remove_Me.{service,timer}
```

Now, `systemctl --user list-timers *Remove*` shows no units.