# Systemd transient timer created with systemd-run is not shown in listed units

Tags: scheduling, systemd-timer

Some time ago, I created a systemd timer using the command:

```
systemd-run --on-calendar='*-*-01 12:00:00' --description='Update root hints for unbound' --property='After=network.target' --timer-property='Persistent=true' /usr/bin/curl -o /etc/unbound/root.hints https://www.internic.net/domain/named.cache
```

After creating this timer, it was assigned a random name `run-u1021`.

Fast-forward to today, I wanted to see the status of the timer so I run the command:

```
systemctl list-timers --all
```

It is not listed in there.

I checked `/var/lib/systemd/timers/`, to see that it contains a stamp file with the name `stamp-run-u1021.timer`.

Running `stat` on this file shows that it was last modified `2020-05-09`, which also corresponds to the stat information for the file `/etc/unbound/root.hints`.

```
➜ stat /var/lib/systemd/timers/stamp-run-u1021.timer
  File: /var/lib/systemd/timers/stamp-run-u1021.timer
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 803h/2051d  Inode: 9438418     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-05-09 23:40:46.628653123 -0600
Modify: 2020-05-09 23:40:46.628653123 -0600
Change: 2020-05-09 23:40:46.628653123 -0600
 Birth: 2020-05-09 23:40:46.628653123 -0600
```

So this timer has been run atleast once, but my question is, where is it located? And how come systemd does not show it? Is that something to do with the way it was created?

---

The next run of the timer:

```
➜ systemd-analyze calendar '*-*-01 12:00:00'               
Normalized form: *-*-01 12:00:00            
    Next elapse: Mon 2020-06-01 12:00:00 CST
       (in UTC): Mon 2020-06-01 18:00:00 UTC
       From now: 1 day 22h left
```

Shows that the timer will be activated in less than 2 days from now. I will wait and see if it actually activates, but in the meanwhile, if someone can answer where the transient timer and its service was created, that would be helpful.

I have also taken a look at this question: [Removing a timer created with "systemd-run --on-calendar"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385490/removing-a-timer-created-with-systemd-run-on-calendar)
However, their problem is different in that systemd actually shows the timer, but they are just having a hard time removing it. In my case, the timer is not showing up in systemd, but still seems to be alive.

Comment: `uptime`? the analyze command is generic and does not imply existence of any timer.

Comment: @frostschutz running the `uptime` command: `16:59:05 up  5:34,  1 user,  load average: 2.53, 1.74, 1.42`

Comment: You are aware that systemd-run transient timers/units do not survive reboots?

Comment: @frostschutz that's exactly what I was trying to understand. Thank you. I kept reading the docs and no where does it mention this.